# Spring Framework: Search Properties by Name

Tags: spring

I've a .properties file. I can inject properties into a bean as needed. Now, I want to be able to search a property by name.

Example:

```
conf.properties:
a.persons=person1,person2,person3
a.gender=male
```

I can inject these properties by using annotations. For example,

```
private @Value("${a.persons}") String[] persons
```

In addition to this, I'd like to search the value of a property given a name, but I'm not sure how to go about it. An example would be something like:

```
properties.get("a.gender")
```

which should return the String "male".

Is this really possible?

**UPDATE**: I have used `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` as shown below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:META-INF/config/server.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:META-INF/config/ke/dev.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

How should I change this so that I can inject it into my bean? How would I access the properties? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how you configured injection of these properties.

- If you use [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html), you can declare your `Properties` as a bean and inject it into `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` as `properties` (instead of `locations`). This way you can also inject your `Properties` directly into your bean.
- If you use [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html), you can inject `Environment` into your bean, and properties would be available through it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @axtavt. I'll test this out and let you know my findings.

Comment: I have the above in my Spring config (See the updated question). As shown, I'm using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` (your first suggestion). How can I change this so that I can inject it into my bean? How would I access the properties. An example will be appreciated very much.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I've come up with the solution posted below as an answer, hoping it'll help someone else. I'm accepting your answer because it saved me a huge amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Following suggestions by @axtavt, I created the bean shown below to help me search for properties given the name of that property. I've leveraged @Environment and @PropertySource in my solution. I'm using Spring 3.1, so this solution might not work with earlier versions of Spring.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource( "/META-INF/config/ke/dev.properties" )
@Service( value = "keConfigurer" )
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public Environment getEnv() {
        return env;
    }

    public void setEnv(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }


}
```

I inject this bean in any other class I wish to use it in. For example:

```
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceConfiguration cfg;

    String testProp = cfg.getEnv().getProperty("prop.name");
}
```

I hope it helps someone else.